# regex_replace doesn't work on Windows

Tags: c++, regex, windows, std

I made a program on Linux, but now I want to make it compatible with Windows. So I compiled my libraries in Windows, created a Code::Blocks project, and starting adapting some functions and variables that don't suit to Windows.

But there is a function that I don't understand why it doesn't work, regex_replace(). #include  doesn't give an error, and regex_match neither. Here is my function:

```
string str = "hey guys";
str = regex_replace(string str, regex("guys"), "girls");
```

And 'str' is now "hey girls".

But when I compile on Windows, it gives me this error: "no matching function for call to 'regex_replace'". I searched a little bit, but I didn't find anything interesting.

So what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Probably a problem of compiler / standard library versions. Which compiler (and version) are you using on both Linux and Windows?

Comment: did you `#include <regexp>`? did you try `std::regex_replace`?

Comment: @aleguna - `#include <regex>`, not `regexp`.

Comment: On Linux (in fact MacOS), I had used XCode. On Windows, I'm using Code::Blocks with MinGW. I included <regex> and tried std::regex_replace ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That's a code problem, not a windows problem. Your code compiles neither on Linux, nor on Windows:

```
str = regex_replace(string str, regex("guys"), "girls");
                    ^^^^^^
                    not allowed there
```

Comment: Ok, this is something I didn't know. I tried with str.c_str(), but it didn't work too. What type should I put? Notice that it worked on MacOS ;=)